# Where can I get bigger amount of test BTC?

Tags: testnet, testing, faucets

We are conducting some testing with the end users of our application and I need a bigger amount of test BTC for it. Using faucets, I can get 0.1 or 0.01 per request with captcha, but I need something around 100. Is there any place, where I can get this amount at once?
Cheers.

Comment: I know someone who can sell you test Bitcoins instantly but that is not something I advise because Test Bitcoins should be available for free. However, if you want to buy them, reach out to  ussain bold at gmail

Answer (score 2):

If you need 100 coins, you should use `regtest` mode, this is a message from a faucet website:

> Please do not ask me to send a coin outside the faucet!
>   My stocks of coins are shrinking and generation new coins is becoming more and more difficult.
>
> If you really need a lot of testing coins, try some other solution. For example:
>   bitcoin-testnet-box
>   bitcoin-regnet

[Link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=950331.0)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @luong-nguyen's post above, if yours is a commercial operation you have a case to buy [old mining equipment](https://www.ebay.com/b/Virtual-Currency-Miners/179171) and mine your own testnet coins.

[Jameson Lopp](https://www.lopp.net/bitcoin-information.html) wrote about this [here](https://medium.com/@lopp/how-to-solo-mine-on-bitcoin-s-testnet-6073c917b495)